# Unable to move scroll bar to top after closing Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Button at the end of page that calls Bootstrap Modal. I'm using the Modal to send and receive data using Ajax. After ajax success and closing of Modal, I want to move the scrollbar at the top of the page.
Code

```
$.ajax({
  URL: "",
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.iscorrect) {
      $("#modal").modal("hide");
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behaviour: "smooth"
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Modal HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius:6px;">

      <div class="modal-header" style="border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="setHeader"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Add Data</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="esicModalBody">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On debugging the code I see the scroll bar is at the top of the page. But after the debugging is complete(Bootstrap Modal Js is executed) the scroll bar is at the bottom(where bootstrap modal is). I tried moving scroll bar on hidden.bs.modal event too. But the scroll bar comes below.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please post your modal html code

Comment: did you get any error in comsole?

Comment: Nope, no error sir. I think bootstrap JS brings the scroll bar to its original position.

Answer (score 1):

There were some missing brackets, try this one:

```
$.ajax({
      URL: "",
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.iscorrect) {
          $("#modal").modal("hide");
          window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            behaviour: "smooth"
          })
        }
      }
});
```

---

Old Version

There is no property name `scroll` in the window object. Instead, you should use the `scrollTo` property, like this:

```
window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Comment: Sir, I know about the ScrollTo method of JS. I'll edit the question it was a mistake.

Comment: @Therii Updated code, review it and ask question if any.